# How to make a bundle with import dependencies coming from a global object?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Suppose I have this code:

```js
import {foo} from 'lib/path/to/foo'
import {bar} from 'lib/path/to/somewhere/bar'
import {baz} from 'lib/path/baz'

console.log(foo, bar, baz)
```

I need the output bundle to get any import from the `lib` package from a global with flat structure. For example, the output bundle would have something like this:

```js
console.log(LIB.foo, LIB.bar, LIB.baz)
```

or

```js
const {foo} = LIB
const {bar} = LIB
const {baz} = LIB

console.log(foo, bar, baz)
```

Basically we assume that anything imported from `lib` (under any path) will be looked up on a global object, where the global object has everything in a flat structure, and no nested objects. Or in other words, this would be wrong:

```js
// This is what we do not want:
const {foo} = LIB.path.to
const {bar} = LIB.path.to.somewhere
const {baz} = LIB.path

console.log(foo, bar, baz)
```

Is there some Webpack magic that can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you should try [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge).
You create some basic config,then second one(THREE). Then you merge them with webpack-merge. In that case you have two separate builds, and use them as you wish.

Nice examples could be found [here.](https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-separate-your-webpack-configs/)

Comment: Thanks, I know about webpack-merge. But I'm curious as to what actual config will achieve the OP.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a magic in webpack. But you can export [multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) in one `webpack.config.js` file where you should be able to share those same configs.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use multiple configs, but I'm asking about how to handle source code in two particular ways. Not sure what the configs are. For example, in one bundle, `import {foo} from 'path/to/foo' would results in the `foo` dependency being bundled, but in the other bundle I need `import {foo} from 'path/to/foo' to get `foo` from `SOME_GLOBAL.foo` (rather than it being bundled).

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you ever tried https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/?

Comment: I've tried externals before, but unless I missed it, I didn't see a way to tell it how to map the imported items to a flat global object.